# Resolving dependencies in Eclipse for Fitnesse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ivy, fitnesse

My goal is to run unit tests in fitnesse.responders.run.slimResponder for testing my DataFlex SlimRunner implementation. So I downloaded the Fitnesse source code, and made it a new Java project in Eclipse. I was able to compile it by selecting Run As Ant Build (2) on the build.xml file. But in order to resolve include errors in the Problems view in Eclipse, I ended up manually adding dozens of external JARs by hand. I found that Maven/Ivy had apparently downloaded the jars as part of the Ant build. But somehow these were not added to the Java Build Path.

It seems reasonable to me to assume that there should be an easier way to set up the Java Build Path than to add the JAR files manually, since build.xml apparently contains all this information already. What am I missing?

Comment: Add those dependencies into your pom file and they will automatically added to your path wihtin Eclipse. For fintnesse there exists a maven plugin which supports running fitness. Why are you using Ant build?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the pointer! I am now trying to use Maven. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461150/how-can-i-get-fitnesse-into-eclipse-from-the-maven-central-repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fitnesse [Readme.md](https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/blob/master/README.md) mentions using Apache Ivy for dependency management. Download IvyDE from Eclipse Marketplace, and set it up (use the ivy.xml that is part of the Fitnesse source code).